# Emit custom events through Slack API

Tags: slack-api, hubot

I'm trying to find a way to send events to a hubot running on Slack from, say, a python script. I've looked at the Events API documentation, but it only talks about how to receive information on events from Slack. Is there any way to emit an event to slack through the API?

Comment: Please specify what your want to achieve by sending events to Slack and people may be able to help you better with your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can only receive events from Slack with the [Events API](https://api.slack.com/events-api). But they are many other ways to interact with the Slack using the normal [Slack API](https://api.slack.com/methods), e.g. sending messages to a channel.